# Get output as a list from time module

Tags: python, list, time, request

I have a code that running in every 2 seconds. This code prints the coordinate information every two seconds. I want to collect these coordinates in a list but I cannot. How can I do that ?

Code:

```
import time
import requests
import schedule



def executeSomething():


    r = requests.get('https://get.geojs.io/')

    ip_request = requests.get("https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip.json")
    ippAdd = ip_request.json()["ip"]

    url = 'https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo/' + ippAdd + '.json'
    geo_request = requests.get(url)
    geo_data = geo_request.json()


    co=[]

    co.append([float(geo_data["latitude"]),float(geo_data["longitude"])])

    print(co)


schedule.every(2).seconds.do(executeSomething)#This code run every 10 seconds
#schedule.every().hour.do(executeSomething())



while 1:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
[[39.9208, 32.8375]]
[[39.7856, 32.2174]]
```

But I want output like this:

```
[[39.9208, 32.8375], [39.7856, 32.2174]]
```

Edit:
I have an another problem. When change **print(co)** to **return co** and import this function to another code and try to get "co" list, I cannot get.

```
import dynamic

d = dynamic.executeSomething()
print(d)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fix your identation.

Comment: I fixed the identation.

Comment: you reset `co` to empty list  inside the function on every run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're resetting the list every time the loop runs by including `co=[]` in your function as it calls the function every time.

Move your `co=[]` above and outside of the function.

```
import time
import requests
import schedule

co=[]

def executeSomething():


    r = requests.get('https://get.geojs.io/')

    ip_request = requests.get("https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip.json")
    ippAdd = ip_request.json()["ip"]

    url = 'https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo/' + ippAdd + '.json'
    geo_request = requests.get(url)
    geo_data = geo_request.json()

    co.append([float(geo_data["latitude"]),float(geo_data["longitude"])])

    print(co)


schedule.every(2).seconds.do(executeSomething)#This code run every 10 seconds
#schedule.every().hour.do(executeSomething())



while 1:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank yoy so much @GazSte